# Unpivot large SQL table and update same table at the same time? (limited by space)

Tags: sql-server

My server at work is very low on space, which we are currently working to resolve. However, we also have some quick deadlines coming up where we need to get this data in there asap.

Origin table: 1.5 billion rows
Unpivotted table: will have 11x 1.5billion rows......~17 billion rows

Is there a way to unpivot the origin table and store that over the origin table at the same time? Normally, I would just store it as a new table and then drop the old table. However, in this case it is not an option. I already tried that and errored due to space limitations.

Comment: If you need space, you need space, end of. If you need to cut corners add a new file group and put a data file on some external storage.

Comment: Process it in chunks. Unpivot a million rows, writing in to the new table, then delete them from the source table. Repeat 1500 times.

Comment: Can you use a view?

Comment: @MatBailie I suppose I could do that. Whats the best way to go about doing that? Just Select * into [new table] from [old table] where state = Alabama......? Then delete all of Alabama from old table. Then do next state and so on? Or is there a better way to do it without worrying about losing data? Seems like that should work and be lossless though

Comment: @Stu could you please elaborate on the file group? Not sure what you mean. I dont know if an external storage device would work though as this is for work and those types of things are weirdly difficult to get approved.

Comment: @alexherm How would a view work? It would have to requery the 1.5billion row dataset each time it ran? Or do you mean something else. please explain. The query itself would take a few days to run each time

Comment: If you can add some temporary external storage you can add a file group and put data file(s) on the external storage, and then create the table `on <filegroupname>`. you might then be able to drop the original table and migrate data from the new filegroup back to an existing filegroup, depending; using row & page compression on the new table, obviously.

Comment: I'm guessing based on your SSMS tag (which by the way is a client tool, not related to your question) that this is about SQL Server. Knowing which RDBMS it is, is very important in questions like this.

Comment: Go to the store and buy a 2TB SSD drive for $200. Then add a new file to the database stored on that drive

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited space I'm not sure that doing it it chunks will meet "quick deadlines" and I would pursue adding a new filegroup and a new file to it using ALTER DATABASE ADD FILE. Then, create the unpivoted table using SELECT INTO and specify the new filegroup using the ON clause.

```
-- Create a new filegroup and add a file to it
ALTER DATABASE [database_name]
ADD FILEGROUP [filegroup_name];

ALTER DATABASE [database_name]
ADD FILE (
  NAME = [file_name],
  FILENAME = 'C:\path\to\filegroup\file.ndf',
  SIZE = 100GB,
  MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
  FILEGROWTH = 10GB
)
TO FILEGROUP [filegroup_name];

-- Create the temporary table on the new filegroup
SELECT *
INTO [filegroup_name].[unpivoted_table]
FROM (
  SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11
  FROM origin_table
) AS t
UNPIVOT (
  value FOR col IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11)
) AS unpvt
ON [filegroup_name];

-- Optional: Rename the origin table
EXEC sp_rename 'origin_table', 'origin_table_backup';

-- Copy the unpivoted table to where the origin table is normally stored
SELECT *
INTO origin_table
FROM unpivoted_table;

-- Drop the backup table, once the oigin_table is verified
-- DROP TABLE origin_table_backup;
```

Obviously this can be broken into separate steps to suit, and handling both a backup table and the new table in the currently limited space may not be possible so you may want to delay overwriting "origin_table" until you have resolved the current lack of space. Until you have the origin_table rebuilt perhaps use the unpivoted_table in lieu.